# Set the title of Navigation Bar created in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I have a modal view controller whose view comes from a XIB.  I want it to have the same look and feel as the rest of my navigation based app, but it's not a view that's pushed to the navigation stack, it's presented modally.  I dragged a UINavigationBar in and made it an outlet, but it doesn't have a title property to set.  I have two fields that can bring up this modal view, and I want the title set differently depending on which one creates the modal view.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

`UINavigationBar`'s manage a stack of `UINavigationItem`s much like a `UINavigationController` manager a stack of `UIViewController`s. To set what is visible directly, you should use either `pushNavigationItem:animated:` or `setItems:animated:` using the navigationItem of the view controller you want the bar to reflect.

eg:

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"A custom title";
[self.navigationBar pushNavigationItem:self.navigationItem animated:NO];
```

The above code where you have a property `navigationBar` which references the stand-alone navigation bar.

If you don't want to manage it yourself, you can do as mplappert suggested and nest your view controller (without a stand-alone `UINavigationBar`) in a `UINavigationController` and present the navigation controller modally instead of your view controller.

Answer (score 64):

Also found this easier way if you've already defined a UINavigationBar in your IB. Assuming self.navigationBar is your IBOutlet:

```
self.navigationBar.topItem.title = title;
```

Comment: in my case: self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"title"

Answer (score 8):

(Using XCode 4.5.2) Found a method that works directly in Interface Builder - without setting in code.

With the ViewController object selected in (IB), under the Identity Inspector there is a section labeled "**User Defined Runtime Attributes**".
I added the keyPath "title" of type String and set it to the value I wanted.

Tested and this works when pushed onto a Nav Controller stack and when opened modally (with a Modal Nav Controller of course).

Comment: How to localize this value?

Answer (score 4):

viewcontroller.h file in create iboutlet of the navigation item

```
     @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationItem *navigationBarTitle;
```

- Named it "navigationBarTitle"

in viewcontroller.m file in add the code in super viewDidLoad

```
      self.navigationBarTitle.title = @"Favorites";
```

connect the storybord in navigation bar item to navigationBarTitle.

Answer (score 0):

in my .h file

- Dragged the Child of the navigation item from the storyboard into the .h file
- Named it "navigationBarTitle"

in my .m file

- Added self.navigationBarTitle.title = @"Some Title";

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Simplest way:

```
[[[self.navigationController navigationBar] topItem] setTitle:@"The Title"];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use existing navigation bar with following code

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Calender"
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply put your `UIViewController` into a new `UINavigationController`s view controller stack and present that navigation controller modally.