# Setting Navigation Item Title in a modal view

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

In reviewing the existing answers, I think [Steve's question and codelark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670907/set-the-title-of-navigation-bar-created-in-interface-builder) comes the closet to my issue. But I am missing something here.

My xib for the modal view:
IFDNewFormViewController.xib:

```
View Controller
> Table View
>> View
>>> Navigation Bar
>>>> Navigation Item - New Form
>> View
>>> Toolbar
>>>> Bar Button Item - Cancel
>>>> Bar Button Item - Flexible Space
>>>> Bar Button Item - Done
```

My method that gets called at a button press:

```
IFDNewFormViewController.m:

- (void) newFormDisplay:(id)sender {
    // Show the Create Flightlog View
    IFDNewFormViewController *newForm = [[IFDNewFormViewController alloc] init];
    newForm.flightlogDelegate = self;
    newForm.dataType = [self ifdDataType];
    newForm.displayDataType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"New %@",[self displayDataType]];
    newForm.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Title %@",[self displayDataType]];
    newForm.navigationItem.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"NavItem.Title %@",[self displayDataType]];
    newForm.navigationController.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"NavController.Title %@",[self displayDataType]];
    newForm.modalViewController.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ModalViewController.Title %@",[self displayDataType]];


    NSLog(@"iFDListViewController_Pad:newFormDisplay start form for dataType=%@ (%@)",[self ifdDataType], [self displayDataType]);
    [self presentModalViewController:newForm animated:YES];
    [newForm release];
}
```

I have set the title in xib:

Navigation Item - New Form -> title.

That title is the one on displayed on the view. Using the information found in this forum I added the following lines:

```
newForm.navigationItem.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"NavItem.Title %@",[self displayDataType]];
newForm.navigationController.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"NavController.Title %@",[self displayDataType]];
newForm.modalViewController.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ModalViewController.Title %@",[self displayDataType]];
```

Still no joy.

I am missing something here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are not pushing this view controller onto a UINavigationController, setting newForm.navigationItem.title won't do the trick.

It looks like you are pushing a modal view controller that contains it's own navigation bar.  In that case, you'll probably need to create your own reference to it and tie the bar in the xib to it.

In IFDNewFormViewController.h create an instance variable

```
    UINavigationBar *customNavBar;
```

and an outlet property

```
    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet *UINavigationBar customNavBar;
```

In IFDNewFormViewController.m:

```
    @synthesize customNavBar;
```

Be sure to release it in dealloc and set to nil in viewDidUnload.

When editing the xib, right click on your navigation bar then click and drag the open circle next to "New Referencing Outlet" up to the file's owner and select customNavBar.  That way the property will contain the bar from your xib after it is loaded.

When you init your IFDNewFormViewController, be sure to use the following:

```
    IFDNewFormViewController *newForm = [[IFDNewFormViewController] alloc] initWithNibName:@"whatever-the-file-name-is" bundle:nil];
```

Or the data in the xib won't even be used.

Comment: I have added the suggested code. I needed to add the type in the @property line. After the IFDNewFormViewController is allocated, when I set the title, there is no error, but xcode shows from a breakpoint set at the end of the .title= lines, "newFormNavBar (UINavigationBar *) 0x0". I verified in the xib that when clicking on View Controller -> Table View -> View -> Navigation Bar, under Referencing Outlets: newFormNavBar <-- File Owner. No change in the Nav Bar title. Still reads "New Form" as set in the xib.

Comment: I did get this to work with a few changes to the solution offered by @tlbrack. Changes: 1. I referenced the UINavigationItem, 2. Moved line line: `newFormNavItem.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Title %@",[self displayDataType]];` to `viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` in IFDNewFormViewController.m. Why isn't newFormNavItem inited after ` IFDNewFormViewController *newForm = [[IFDNewFormViewController] alloc] initWithNibName:@"whatever-the-file-name-is" bundle:nil];` is called? Should I add a solution to this question with the final changes, or mark @tlbrack's as the solution?